# jQuery FlipClock working for a single time when using multiple time

Tags: jquery, flipclock

I have taken a flip clock. I want to use it multiple times on my page. It is working fine only for single time. But when I am doing repeat the markup it is working for the single time and for rest of the type it's not working.
The jQuery code goes like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    setInterval(function() {
  doFlip(3);
}, 1000);

function doFlip(numberIndex) {

  var currentNumberElement = $(".number:eq(" + numberIndex + ")");

  var currentNumber = Number(currentNumberElement.attr("data-number"));    

  currentNumber--;

  if (currentNumber < 0) {
    currentNumber = 9;

    if (numberIndex > 0) {
      doFlip(--numberIndex);
    }
  } 

  currentNumberElement.addClass("flip");

  setTimeout(function() {
    currentNumberElement.attr("data-number", currentNumber);

    currentNumberElement.removeClass("flip");
  }, 500);
}
  });
```

and the markup goes like this

```
<span class="number" data-number="9">
  <span class="primary">
  </span>
  <span class="secondary">
  </span>
</span>
<span class="number" data-number="9">
  <span class="primary">
  </span>
  <span class="secondary">
  </span>
</span>
<span class="number" data-number="9">
  <span class="primary">
  </span>
  <span class="secondary">
  </span>
</span>
<span class="number" data-number="9">
  <span class="primary">
  </span>
  <span class="secondary">
  </span>
</span>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/mhyegpaj/) link where it's working for the single time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group each instance within an element, and run the timer for each instance like

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.flipper').each(function() {
    var $flip = $(this);
    setInterval(function() {
      doFlip($flip, 3);
    }, 1000);
  })

  function doFlip($flip, numberIndex) {

    var currentNumberElement = $flip.find(".number:eq(" + numberIndex + ")");

    var currentNumber = Number(currentNumberElement.attr("data-number"));

    currentNumber--;

    if (currentNumber < 0) {
      currentNumber = 9;

      if (numberIndex > 0) {
        doFlip($flip, --numberIndex);
      }
    }

    currentNumberElement.addClass("flip");

    setTimeout(function() {
      currentNumberElement.attr("data-number", currentNumber);

      currentNumberElement.removeClass("flip");
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
body {

  font-size: 14px;

}

@keyframes animate-top {

  0% {

    background: #3e3e3e;

    /* Old browsers */

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

    /* FF3.6+ */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #3e3e3e), color-stop(100%, #2b2b2b));

    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

    /* IE10+ */

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3e3e3e', endColorstr='#2b2b2b', GradientType=0);

  }

  100% {

    color: #474747;

    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0.35em) translateZ(5px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }

}

@keyframes animate-bottom {

  0% {

    color: #474747;

    opacity: 1;

  }

  100% {

    transform: translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

    opacity: 1;

  }

}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-top {

  0% {

    background: #3e3e3e;

    /* Old browsers */

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

    /* FF3.6+ */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #3e3e3e), color-stop(100%, #2b2b2b));

    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

    /* IE10+ */

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3e3e3e', endColorstr='#2b2b2b', GradientType=0);

  }

  100% {

    color: #474747;

    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0.35em) translateZ(5px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  }

}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-bottom {

  0% {

    color: #474747;

    opacity: 1;

  }

  100% {

    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateY(0) translateZ(0) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

    opacity: 1;

  }

}

.number {

  position: relative;

  float: left;

  margin-right: 5px;

  font-size: 5em;

  width: 1em;

  height: 1.5em;

}

.number span {

  position: absolute;

  display: block;

  font-weight: bold;

  text-align: center;

  box-sizing: border-box;

  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

  color: white;

  width: 1em;

  height: 1.5em;

  perspective: 7.14em;

}

.number span:before {

  display: block;

  height: 0.75em;

  overflow: hidden;

  line-height: 1.52em;

  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

  border-radius: 20% 20% 0 0;

  background: #3e3e3e;

  /* Old browsers */

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

  /* FF3.6+ */

  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #3e3e3e), color-stop(100%, #2b2b2b));

  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

  /* Opera 11.10+ */

  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

  /* IE10+ */

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3e3e3e 0%, #2b2b2b 100%);

  /* W3C */

  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3e3e3e', endColorstr='#2b2b2b', GradientType=0);

  /* IE6-9 */

}

.number span:after {

  display: block;

  height: 0.75em;

  overflow: hidden;

  line-height: 0;

  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

  border-radius: 0 0 20% 20%;

  transition: color 100ms, background-color 100ms;

  background: #252525;

  /* Old browsers */

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #252525 0%, #070707 100%);

  /* FF3.6+ */

  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #252525), color-stop(100%, #070707));

  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #252525 0%, #070707 100%);

  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #252525 0%, #070707 100%);

  /* Opera 11.10+ */

  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #252525 0%, #070707 100%);

  /* IE10+ */

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #252525 0%, #070707 100%);

  /* W3C */

  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#252525', endColorstr='#070707', GradientType=0);

  /* IE6-9 */

}

.flip .primary:before {

  animation: animate-top 250ms;

  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  -webkit-animation: animate-top 250ms;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  background: #000000;

  /* Old browsers */

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #303030 100%);

  /* FF3.6+ */

  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000000), color-stop(100%, #303030));

  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #303030 100%);

  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #303030 100%);

  /* Opera 11.10+ */

  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #303030 100%);

  /* IE10+ */

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 0%, #303030 100%);

  /* W3C */

  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#303030', GradientType=0);

  /* IE6-9 */

}

.flip .primary:after {

  animation: animate-bottom 250ms;

  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  animation-delay: 250ms;

  -webkit-animation: animate-bottom 250ms;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  -webkit-animation-delay: 250ms;

}

.primary:after {

  opacity: 0;

  transform: translateX(0) translateY(-0.28em) translateZ(0.35em) rotateX(91deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateY(-0.28em) translateZ(0.35em) rotateX(91deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

}

.primary {

  z-index: 2;

}

.secondary {

  z-index: 1;

}

/* Number 0 */

[data-number="0"] span.primary:before {

  content: "0";

}

[data-number="0"] span.secondary:after {

  content: "0";

}

[data-number="0"] span.secondary:before {

  content: "9";

}

[data-number="0"] span.primary:after {

  content: "9";

}

/* Number 9 */

[data-number="9"] span.primary:before {

  content: "9";

}

[data-number="9"] span.secondary:after {

  content: "9";

}

[data-number="9"] span.secondary:before {

  content: "8";

}

[data-number="9"] span.primary:after {

  content: "8";

}

/* Number 8 */

[data-number="8"] span.primary:before {

  content: "8";

}

[data-number="8"] span.secondary:after {

  content: "8";

}

[data-number="8"] span.secondary:before {

  content: "7";

}

[data-number="8"] span.primary:after {

  content: "7";

}

/* Number 7 */

[data-number="7"] span.primary:before {

  content: "7";

}

[data-number="7"] span.secondary:after {

  content: "7";

}

[data-number="7"] span.secondary:before {

  content: "6";

}

[data-number="7"] span.primary:after {

  content: "6";

}

/* Number 6 */

[data-number="6"] span.primary:before {

  content: "6";

}

[data-number="6"] span.secondary:after {

  content: "6";

}

[data-number="6"] span.secondary:before {

  content: "5";

}

[data-number="6"] span.primary:after {

  content: "5";

}

/* Number 5 */

[data-number="5"] span.primary:before {

  content: "5";

}

[data-number="5"] span.secondary:after {

  content: "5";

}

[data-number="5"] span.secondary:before {

  content: "4";

}

[data-number="5"] span.primary:after {

  content: "4";

}

/* Number 4 */

[data-number="4"] span.primary:before {

  content: "4";

}

[data-number="4"] span.secondary:after {

  content: "4";

}

[data-number="4"] span.secondary:before {

  content: "3";

}

[data-number="4"] span.primary:after {

  content: "3";

}

/* Number 3 */

[data-number="3"] span.primary:before {

  content: "3";

}

[data-number="3"] span.secondary:after {

  content: "3";

}

[data-number="3"] span.secondary:before {

  content: "2";

}

[data-number="3"] span.primary:after {

  content: "2";

}

/* Number 2 */

[data-number="2"] span.primary:before {

  content: "2";

}

[data-number="2"] span.secondary:after {

  content: "2";

}

[data-number="2"] span.secondary:before {

  content: "1";

}

[data-number="2"] span.primary:after {

  content: "1";

}

/* Number 1 */

[data-number="1"] span.primary:before {

  content: "1";

}

[data-number="1"] span.secondary:after {

  content: "1";

}

[data-number="1"] span.secondary:before {

  content: "0";

}

[data-number="1"] span.primary:after {

  content: "0";

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flipper">
    <span class="number" data-number="9">
        <span class="primary"></span>
        <span class="secondary"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="number" data-number="9">
        <span class="primary"></span>
        <span class="secondary"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="number" data-number="9">
        <span class="primary"></span>
        <span class="secondary"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="number" data-number="9">
        <span class="primary"></span>
        <span class="secondary"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="flipper">
    <span class="number" data-number="9">
        <span class="primary"></span>
        <span class="secondary"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="number" data-number="9">
        <span class="primary"></span>
        <span class="secondary"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="number" data-number="9">
        <span class="primary"></span>
        <span class="secondary"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="number" data-number="9">
        <span class="primary"></span>
        <span class="secondary"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```